# How to block multiple jobs using the build blocker plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have 4 Jobs set up in Jenkins

- ViewScreen - A
- ViewScreen - B
- ViewScreen - C
- Build - TRAP

When I build `ViewScreen - A`, I want to make sure that it is blocked if any of the other three jobs are running. I installed the build blocker plugin in Jenkins in hopes to accomplish this.

I added `Build - TRAP` as a blocking job when configuring `ViewScreen - A`. Now `ViewScreen - A` is blocked if `Build - TRAP` is running.

How can I add the other jobs as blocking jobs? I've tried adding each job on its own line in the Blocking jobs section, but that didn't seem to work. My build would only be blocked by the job listed first. So if my blocking jobs sections is entered like below, only Build - TRAP running causes my build to go into the queue.

```
Build - TRAP
ViewScreen - B
ViewScreen - C
```

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a very silly thing that I overlooked. When typing my question, I didn't type out the exact job names, just made up ones as examples. My real jobs had parenthesis in them. I didn't comment out the parenthesis, which was causing the issue

Use `ViewScreen - \(A\)` instead of `ViewScreen - (A)`